# How to curve a Mapview and shadow it's borders in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios5, mkmapview, shadow, curve

i have tried curving a UIView,UIImage view and also set shadows and corner/border radius to them as well.My doubt is is the same possible with mapview,can we curve a mapview?
i used a curved view and inserted a mapview in it but that resulted as an error so i'm asking for help ,any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "curved view", but if you want to have a map view with non-rectangular, curved borders, you could try setting a CALayer clipping path, like this:

```
UIBezierPath* someBezierPath = ...;
CAShapeLayer* mask = [CAShapeLayer layer];
[mask setPath:[someBezierPath CGPath]];
[map.layer setMask:mask];
[someBezierPath release];
```